# What is the meaing of the ^ in a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have searched the Apache docs for version 2.4 (which appear to be in some disarray) looking for the answer to my question. I believe that it forms part of the rule pattern semantics
RewriteRule *Pattern* Target Flags but cannot find an explanation such a simple question and the source is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

ModRewrite uses regular expressions to match rules to request URIs, and the `^` character is a standard metacharacter in most regular expression dialects.  It serves two distinct purposes:

- When it appears at the beginning of a pattern, it anchors the pattern so that it must match starting at the beginning of the input.  Without that, most regular expression dialects will match the pattern to any part of the input: `^foo` matches `foo` and `foobar`, but not `Redfoo`.
- When it appears as the first character in a character class, it negates the sense of the class.  Thus `[abcd]` matches `a`, `food`, and `caca`, but not `mutton`, whereas `[^abcd]` matches `food` and `mutton` but not `a` or `caca`.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation on [this website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html):

> Negative character class - matches any character not specified